# Find historical node count of node pool

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-vm-scale-set

We are running a Kubernetes cluster on AKS. The cluster runs on multiple node pools. Autoscaling is enabled to make sure nodes are added or removed when necessary.

I can see the current used amount of nodes by navigating to AKS -> Settings -> Node pools on the Azure Portal. However, I'm not able to get this information historically.

A question I want to find an answer for:
How many nodes were active for node pool 'x' last night?

I couldn't find any metrics for the AKS and Virtual Machine Scale Set resources to answer my question. What are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is not such a metric. a small workaround could be:

In the Portal go to your AKS -> Monitoring -> Metrics. In the Scope select your AKS, Scope Namespace is `Container service` and then you have the following metrics:

- `Cluster Health` - determines if the autoscaler will take action on the cluster
- `Unneeded Nodes` - autoscaler mark nodes for deletion

There you can see at least if scaling took place and how many nodes were deleted afterwards so you could calculate the amount of nodes.

Comment: Good one, I will consider this as the accepted answer for now. It seems like there aren't any better other options for now.

Answer (score 1):

In the standard AKS metrics, there is a metric "Total number of available cpu cores in a managed cluster". It cannot be dimensioned into nodepools unfortunately, but you can at least see the cluster total size and see when up or down-scaling has occurred, either manually or automatically. If you enable "container insights" there maybe more metrics and better granularity available, but that is extra cost and not enabled on our clusters.

Select "Resource type"="kubernetes service" and you should see it in the metric list.